# Sort objects in array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

[Complete code](https://pastebin.com/gsxnTe3F)

I need sort an array based on another array. Currently I have this function that creates new array containing user information.

Each user is defined in JSON string and is stored in MySQL like so:

```
{"Firstname":"John","Lastname":"Smith","Email":"johnsmith@outlook.com"},
{"Firstname":"Hans","Lastname":"Jobens", "Age", "Too old"}
```

I loop every object to get each **header** and then push them into **headers** array.

```
$headers = array("Age", "Email", "Firstname", "Lastname")
```

Then I create new user object for each user row.

```
$user_object = array();
```

And add each header to each user object and fill them with data or placeholder "-"

```
//add missing keys and values
foreach($users as $user){
    //get user from user row
    $row = $user['user'];
    //loop headers for each row
    foreach($headers as $header){
        //check if $header found in each row
        if (!array_key_exists($header,$row)){
            //if not found
            $row->$header = "-";
        }
    }
}
```

Objects are pushed into users array and now they look like this:

```
{"Firstname":"John","Lastname":"Smith","Email":"johnsmith@outlook.com","Age":"-"},
{"Firstname":"Hans","Lastname":"Jobens","Age":"Too old","Email":"-"}
```

But they are not in the right order. I want each user's object keys to maintain their values but be in order by **$headers** array.

Needed format:

```
{"Age":"-","Email":"johnsmith@outlook.com","Firstname":"John","Lastname":"Smith"},
{"Age":"Too old","Email":"-","Firstname":"Hans","Lastname":"Jobens"}
```

[Complete code](https://pastebin.com/gsxnTe3F)

EDIT:

Function in short:

1. Initialize $list, $users and $headers array
2. Get array of user information (stored as javascript object) from
   mysql
3. Decode and loop every user and get each object key
4. Append each new key into $headers array
5. Loop $users again to add missing keys and placeholder (dash mark)
6. Arrange OBJECT by $headers array
7. Append $headers and $users into $list
8. echo json_encode($list)

[image: Console.log]

Comment: `Object are pushed into Users array and now they look like this` - you show a JSON string, not an array.

Comment: Possibly duplicate on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Answer (score 0):

use array_replace function

```
$user_object = array();
foreach($users as $user){
    // array which set order
    $template = array_fill_keys(["Age", "Email", "Firstname", "Lastname"], '-');
    // Get current existing value
    $user_object[] = array_replace($template, $user['user']);
}
print_r($user_object);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/925817)

Comment: Not working at all. What is it even doing? I read the documentation, but it doesn't consider ordering?

Comment: @Jaakkouu It sets order when make template array. Then using array_replace does not change it, just replace value for the same keys

Comment: @splash58 Warning: array_replace(): Argument #2 is not an array in

Comment: @Jaakkouu If i understood right, it should be so - https://eval.in/925838

Comment: @splash58 Not quite there. I added more information to question. Can you check it please? I am dealing with objects inside arrays. These objects need to be arranged by headers array which is dynamically build.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by pushing each corresponding data *`(-) if null`* as you loop thru the `headers`.

```
foreach($users as $key => $user){
    //get user from user row
    $row = $user['user'];
    // Set new row
    $newRow = [];
    // Loop thru headers
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        // Check if row has the header, set '-' if not
        $newRow[$header] = (!array_key_exists($header, $row)) ? '-' : $row[$header];
    }
    // set key of users to newRow
    $users[$key] = $newRow;
}

print_r($users); // Print users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order an array by key using another as a reference by combining uksort() and array_search():

```
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($headers) {
 return array_search($a, $headers) > array_search($b, $headers);
});
```

Comment: uksort + array_search almost 10 times slower (php7.2) then equivalent foreach